# objective c: @synchronized how does it work

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [objective-c : @synchronized, how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810459/objective-c-synchronized-how-does-it-work)

when i have three methods:

```
    -(void)  a {
        @synchronized(self) {
          //part a
        }
     }

    -(void) b {
         @synchronized(self) {
          //part b 
     }

   -(void) c {
        // part c
    }
```

and thread is in part a , then will be part c blocked for other threads?

Comment: that's like asking: "if i eat an apple and a dry cleaner, will it rain in china?" :)

Comment: i just wanted to know if synchronising "self" blocks all object,

Comment: @hop and the answer to that is "yes".  China is a big place. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only `@synchronized` blocks interact with each other. As long as one thread is executing either part `A` or part `B`, no other thread can enter part `A` or part `B`. Part `C` is not affected by this in any way.

Your new comment above made a bit clearer, what you are actually asking.

In `@synchronized(self)`, `self` is not the thing that is locked itself, it *is* *used* as a lock to guarantee that only one thread at a time can enter the `@synchronized` block.

As the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocThreading.html) explains: you can use any object as a semaphore.

The [chapter on synchronization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) has a comprehensive description of all available locking options, btw.

Comment: ok, thank you, i just had doubst about it

Comment: @MarekM: You are welcome! If you like my answer, you can accept it by clicking the check mark. You even get reputation for that.

Comment: thanks, i'm new on stackoverflow and objective c,